# Generate a random password with requirements

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to generate a random password of length of 16 characters containing numbers, alphabets and special characters, but no two special characters should be adjacent
the special characters i am using are `~!@#$%^&*()_+-={}[]:;\?,.|\\`

```js
generateRandomPasswordSelection = function (length, chars) {
      var mask = '';
      if (chars.indexOf('a') > -1) mask += 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
      if (chars.indexOf('A') > -1) mask += 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
      if (chars.indexOf('#') > -1) mask += '0123456789';
      if (chars.indexOf('!') > -1) mask += '~!@#$%^&*()_+-={}[]:;\?,.|\\';
      var result ='';
        for(var i=1; i>=1;i++){
            result = '';
            for (var i = length; i > 0; --i) result += mask[Math.round(Math.random() * (mask.length - 1))];
            if(result.match(new RegExp(/(?!.*[~!@#$%^&*()_+={}[\]:;\?,.|\\-]{2})[A-Za-z0-9]{1,16}$/))){
                console.log(result,'---------------->', 'BREAk')
                break;
            }
        }
      }

  generateRandomPasswordSelection(16,'aA#!');
```

Above one is the code i have tried, but didn't work.How to achieve this?

Comment: What is the chars variable supposed to be? Does this just mean that no 2 of these characters should be next to each other?

Comment: @DovRine
~!@#$%^&*()_+-={}[]:;\?,.|\\  these characters should not be next to each other.

Comment: so what is the second variable for?

Comment: I am using this in bash `head -c 100 </dev/urandom | base64 | head -c "${1:-64}"`. The idea is that a long random base64 string is secure enough.

Answer (score 3):

Uses ES6 syntax, hopefully more readable.

```js
const getRandomElement = arr => {
  const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
  return arr[rand];
}

const generateRandomPasswordSelection = (length) => {
  const uppercase = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'];
  const lowercase = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
  const special = ['~', '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '_', '+', '-', '=', '{', '}', '[', ']', ':', ';', '?', ', ', '.', '|', '\\'];
  const numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];

  const nonSpecial = [...uppercase, ...lowercase, ...numbers];

  let password = '';

  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    // Previous character is a special character
    if (i !== 0 && special.includes(password[i - 1])) {
      password += getRandomElement(nonSpecial);
    } else password += getRandomElement([...nonSpecial, ...special]);
  }

  return password;
}

const password = generateRandomPasswordSelection(16);
console.log(password);
```

Comment: why go to all the trouble of creating the arrays like that? string.split('') is much easier to read and maintain

Comment: I like your avoidance of my while loop by only selecting from regular chars if the current one is special. :)

Comment: This is probably more readable, still:

Comment: password +=
  i !== 0 && special.includes(password[i - 1])
    ? getRandomElement(nonSpecial)
    : getRandomElement([...nonSpecial, ...special]);

Comment: It's more performant to hard-code the arrays than call `String#split` every time you call the function. Typically, you would declare the arrays in another file tucked away and import it into this file.

Comment: This performance benefit seems negligible to me compared to needing to maintain the array down the road.

Comment: I deleted my answer b/c overall, yours is better